# How to select only hovered item from UL list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, slider, jquery-animate, thumbnails

Ok so I have an unordered list that is built by appending li's from a JSON object. What I am trying to do is select only the current LI from the UL when I hover over it. I can get as close as selecting just the :first LI or the last or even or odds or whatever but I can't get it to transform on the the item that is chosen from the list.

The end objective is to have an effect that on LI hover will cycle through multiple actions from a MySql database(but i am far off from accomplishing this). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
$("#thumbnails").hover(function(){
$('#thumbnails > li:first').text("Whats 2 + 2");
});
```

I know this code is wrong, if I just choose LI is will change the text on every single one of them.

The UL is named thumbnails and gets its base from another CSS stylesheet

```
<ul name="thumbnails" id="thumbnails">

</ul>
```

In the end I am basically looking to build something like this 
http://www.melonhtml5.com/demo/metro_gallery/demo2.php

except it will scroll items from a MySql database instead of images. Is this even possible?

Major bonus points if you know of a code example I can just buy instead of having to build this from the ground up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I know what you're asking but it sounds like you want to do something to the LI that's is hovered over without binding an event handler to each one.

If that's the case, then you can use the `on` method to watch the list then listen for its specific LI child like so:

```
$("#myList").on("mouseenter", "li", function () {
     //do stuff here
});

$("#myList").on("mouseleave", "li", function () {
    //stop doing stuff here
});
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/tbwIII/pcEL9/)

more [about the jQuery on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was looking for. From here I basically have to figure out a way to maybe pull from another JSON object or something like that. But this gets me started at least! cheers!